# Visualizing highly dimensional data with response that can take only 3 values?

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2, high-dimensional

**Examples of data**

Consider these data (coded in R)

```
yValue = function(a,b,c,d)
{
    r = runif(1,0.7,1)
    l = (a>3) * b/20 + c/4 * (d<10) + d/11 - a/4
    R = rep(0,length(a))
    R[r > l] = 2
    R[r < l] = 1
    R[b > 6] = 0
    return (R)  
}

set.seed(1)
a=1:5;b=1:8;c=1:4;d=1:12;e=1:7
d = expand.grid(a=1:5,b=1:8,c=1:4,d=1:12,e=1:7)
d$y = as.factor(yValue(d$a,d$b,d$c,d$d))
```

**Goal**

`y` is my response variable and it can take three different values.

**I fail to think of a good way to visualize these data. I would like to visualize the space formed by the explanatory variables `a`,`b`,`c`,`e`,`f` and see which combinations is causing the the `y` variable to take one value or another.**

The best I could find for the moment is something like

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=y)) + facet_grid(d~c+e)
```

[image]

Comment: Are the variables a:e supposed to be continuous or categorical? Do you want to visualize these data to help yourself understand what's going on, or to present to others to make a point (& if so, what)?

Answer (score 2):

For high dimensional data, nothing is going to be as great as 2-D data on a 2-D surface. However, a decent scalable approach is to use displays based parallel axes instead of perpendicular axes.

An array of histograms is one version of this.

[image]

The utility in seeing relationships comes from linked selection, so that if you, say, select the y=1 bin, you see the values of those rows in the other variables.

[image]

You can apply that idea to arrays of other graphs as well, but there is one special kind of graph designed for parallel axes called [parallel coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates), or [parallel sets](https://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/) when applied to categorical data which I have done in this view of your data.

[image]

The areas are colored by the Y variable, so you can see a few Y-specific features, and you can sometimes see pairwise relationships between adjacent axes.

(I made these in JMP, but I believe there are a few options for parallel coordinates in R.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is on the right track. Using geom_tile or [other methods](https://www.r-bloggers.com/search/heatmap) to make a “heatmap” is an effective way to visualize this.

This has also been popularized as a “lasagna plot”. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820275/lasagna-plots-in-r) for more help.

I think plots of this type are usually used with time as the x-axis, but I see no reason why you couldn’t use some other variable instead.

EDIT: I posted this before your edit to the panel plot. I'd have to consider more carefully if a panel of heatmaps is useful or not